# CommandLine Execution from SQL Server not finding CMD variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd, command-line

I am trying to get a SQL Server Agent job to execute in command line the following code. It sets the variable to the server name of the SQL Server instance so that it can reach out to the UNC path and run the executable. This singular line works find when I run it on the server in command line through RDP, but fails when run in SQL Server as type Operating system (CmdExec). The line is:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %i IN (`hostname`) DO SET _exeCall=\\%i\test\test1.exe && %_exeCall%
```

The results from the log are:

```
C:\Windows\system32>SET _exeCall=\\testbox\test\test1.exe   && _exeCall
'%_exeCall%' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The machine is correctly titled testbox, the path and executable file are correct, but it does not appear to understand that it should be executing the variable _exeCall. This works properly when executed on the server in commandline, but not from SQL Server's commandline tool.

Comment: Have you tried putting the commands in PARENTHESIS characters?  `DO (SET _exeCall=\\%i\test\test1.exe && _exeCall)`

Comment: @lit, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I just tried it and it resulted in the same problem. Still, I appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: This looks like it would be a delayedexpansion problem. I am surprise that it works from cmd.exe. What is the "SQL Servers's commandline tool?"

Comment: sorry, I'm not smart enough to answer that one. There's just a dropdown selection item for Operating system (CmdExec)

Comment: Maybe try with PowerShell

Comment: For the purposes of what you've posted, I do not see any reason for creating an intermediate variable. Why not just use `for /f %i in ('hostname')do @\\%i\test\test1.exe`?

Comment: @MartinCairney I agree. Powershell seems a lot easier, but the admins have it locked down hard for some reason.